# Processing - draw() is run after the calling methods have already returned

Tags: java, processing, dropwizard

EDIT: I've created a minimal program that replicates this issue [here](https://gitlab.com/jamiesprax/test-app/)

---

I have an endpoint that calls `draw(node)` in a subclass of `Display` and subsequently `redraw()`. Then it saves the frame to a file then returns it to show in the browser.

For some reason, the endpoint returns the response before the frame has been redrawn which results in the first call being a blank background, and each subsequent endpoint call being the previous frame.

I did some debugging and found that the `draw()` code is only executed after the endpoint method has returned the response instead of where I'd expect it to be executed as part of the method calls.

I've tried some stuff with `finished` variables with while loops to stall it, and some thread sleeping but nothing has worked so far.

I'm using the DropWizard framework and Processing lib v3.3.7

```
@Override
public void settings() {
    size(S_WIDTH, S_HEIGHT);
    noLoop();
}

@Override
public void draw() {
    if (Objects.nonNull(currNode)) { //currNode starts as null
        // Some drawing stuff
    }
}

public void draw(Node node) {
    this.currNode = node;
    redraw();
}
```

Comment: Do you really mean http://www.dropwizard.io/?

Comment: @LutzHorn yeah, why's that?

Comment: It's a little hard to help you, since we can't run your code. You'll have better luck if you post a [mcve]. At the very least, can you please be more specific about what's happening? Do you mean that the `draw(Node)` function is called again before the `draw()` function finishes? (Side note: it's a little hard to talk about this stuff with two functions with the same name. I'd rename the `draw(Node)` function if at all possible.)

Comment: I see nothing in your question that is related to Dropwizard.io. What kind of nodes are you drawing?

Comment: @KevinWorkman Sorry! I threw [this](https://gitlab.com/jamiesprax/test-app/) together which reproduces it. `server src/main/resources/config.yaml` needs to go in the program arguments to run it and the endpoint should be `http://localhost:8080/1/generate?size={int}`. You can compare the browser to the processing window and see it's always one behind by changing the size parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`redraw()` starts a new thread so lock syncing that to the main one solved the issue.

Comment: I believe you also could have called the `loop()` function instead of `redraw()`. You'd then have to call `noLoop()` at the end of `draw()`.